# Drop down menu populated with specific users in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of users called DER's defined with a boolean field `der` as follows

```
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@ders = User.where(der: true, troop: @user.troop)
...
```

end

I would like to generate a drop down menu where each option is the name of each der, but I'm having trouble figuring out `<%= f.select %>` statements in Ruby on Rails. I've tried a bunch of variations and this is the most recent I've tried

```
<% der_array = User.where(der: true, troop: @user.troop).map { |der| [der.name, der.id] } %>
<%= options_for_select(der_array) %>
```

but this just shows text values of the DER names not in a drop down format. What would be the best way to get a drop down menu to populate with the DER's names and send their ID to the controller?

Edit: the working code is

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.collection_select :id, @ders, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try `collection_select`

in view
`<%= f.collection_select :your_field, @ders, :id, :name %>`

Comment: What would `:your_field` be in this case? I'm not sure what that's supposed to point to/reference

Comment: assume the select is in a `form_for @model` block, it should be a field name of the `@model`

Comment: Finally got around to trying this out and it works great! Thank you. Check my edit for the working code